# Use functions with html and angularjs to filter the json response

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm working on an app by which I'm trying to deal with a json response that brings in an array of elements, the response looks like this:

```
{"lookup":[{"id":"679","lookup_id":"1","name":"Individual"},{"id":"680","lookup_id":"2","name":"Corporate"}]}
```

I created a function to fetch the response from the route inside js:

```
$scope.getLookup= function( LookupName){

adsResource.lookup({lookupName: LookupName}, function(result){
    $scope.lookupItem = result.lookup;
        return result.name;

});
```

and inside html file I want to show lookupItem.name only when lookupItem.id matches '1', I thought a filter will get that done for me but it didn't:

{{getLookup('advertisements_classification')|filter: lookupItem.id == '1'}}

Any useful thoughts ?

Comment: can you show your html part ?

Comment: <td>{{getLookup('advertisements_classification')|lookupItem.id == '1'}}</td>  @Dvir

Comment: Lookupitem is a filter that you created? Because you didn't paste the code of it

Comment: no, it is not a filter, it is variable that holds the entire response @Dvir

Comment: You cant use it as a filter

Comment: still not working @Dvir

Comment: can you elaborate more how you are using  getLookup method ,are you looping response .is lookupItem.id == '1' is static